# Pyqt5--Why QApplication.processEvents() failed to update GUI

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am learning to use PyQT5 and QtDesign. The workflow is :Click button->Change a image. But GUI failed to update until QMessege appeared. Here is a code. Firstly, I draw a button named pass_btn, a label named fds_img, by QtDesign.

Then, code as below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtGui
import os, sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
dlg = uic.loadUi('grading_sys.ui')

stepper = 0
img_dir_list = [] #this is a image dir list
dlg.fds_img.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(img_dir_list[stepper]))

def pass_btn():
    global stepper
    if stepper == len(img_dir_list) - 1:
         QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Warning', 'Warning')
         return
    stepper += 1
    dlg.fds_img.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(img_dir_list[stepper]))
    print('Try to refresh')
    QApplication.processEvents()

dlg.pass_btn.clicked.connect(pass_btn)

dlg.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So why I could not refresh the label? Or how could I refresh image when I click the button?

Comment: @Isma Thanks a lot for your comments. I have posted all codes, and I had added an .ui image.

Comment: Hi, the image is unnecessary, you need to include the code from grading_sys.ui (or a small version of it) because we don't have access to that file. Also, your code does not compile (look at the line globle stepper).

Comment: @Isma Thanks for your advices. There is nothing but a label and a button. I import them by line: dlg = uic.loadUi('grading_sys.ui'), instead of converting to python code directly. So should I still need to convert it?

Comment: Your current code does not generate any problems for me, could you share the .ui ?, where are you executing your code ?, besides it is not necessary to use processEvents. Is that all your code or do you have any other code?

Comment: @Isma Thanks a lot for your testing. These were really the whole codes. And I am new to pyqt5. I ran these code in MacOS 10.14.2, Pycharm 2018.3.3. Also, I tried to print logs every step. The codes really ran, but the screen never update until a QMessage or if re-focused to the main window. Do you have any idea about this? Here is the ui file in google drive:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FLiufUzfmwrOqWR9dujr2DEX51mzCub2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks a lot for your testing. I ran these code in MacOS 10.14.2, Pycharm 2018.3.3, Python 3,6.The screen never update until a QMessage appear, or if I tried to re-focused to the main window. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Change `dlg.pass_btn.clicked.connect(pass_btn)` to `dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(pass_btn)`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this by using QTimer. I know it is a waste of CPU, may not efficient enough, but it finally works. But I still confusing about why it did't work before. I solved this as codes below:

First, put all the update codes in a def, then connected it with QTimer, and ran it every second:

```
def refresh_ui():
    print('Try to refresh UI')
    print('Prepare to change image' + str(img_dir_list[stepper]))
    dlg.fds_img.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(img_dir_list[stepper]))

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(refresh_ui)
timer.start(1000)
```

My environment: MacOS 10.14.2, PyCharm 2018.3.3 edu edition, Python 3.6, PyQt5, QtDesign (through Anaconda). Dose this happened because of MacOS?